# Difference between “mix" and "stir"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is the difference between “mix" and "stir"
how to use them.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ELL.  Can you give more details.  Did you look up the words in a dictionary?  What does the dictionary tell you? (you can copy the definitions into the question)  If the dictionary doesn't answer your question, can you explain why?

Comment: Someone can 'stir up trouble' but not 'mix' it, and can 'mix their metaphors' but not 'stir' them.

Comment: @WeatherVane You would be stupid to 'stir up trouble' if you cannot 'mix' it  with the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can mix virtually all substances together but you cannot stir all substances. Only fluids can be stirred**

(Note I am saying fluids not liquids)

**fluid**; a substance that flows and is not solid:

**substance** is a solid, powder, liquid, or gas with particular properties.

I disagree with the dictionary definitions of Stir, you cannot stir a substance but you can stir some substances that are in a fluid state.

**mix** to (cause different substances to) combine, so that the result cannot easily be separated into its parts:

stir; to mix a liquid or other substance by moving an object such as a spoon in a circular pattern: